How to format geom_label() values within plotnine
When I am using plotnine, I can use mizani.labels to format the axis labels as percent strings. Is there a similar method to formate geom_label values? I cannot use label = ml.percent("rate") as this will trigger an error.
import polars as pl
from plotnine import * 
import mizani.labels as ml

df = pl.DataFrame({
  "group": ["A", "B"], 
  "rate": [.511, .634]
})

plot = (ggplot(df, aes(x = "group", y = "rate", label = "rate")) +
geom_col() +
geom_label() +
scale_y_continuous(labels = ml.percent)
)

plot.show()


I can preformat a rate_label before adding my dataframe to ggplot, but I was hoping to avoid this prework as I am able to avoid it when using ggplot in R.
df = df.with_columns(rate_label = (pl.col("rate") * 100).round(1).cast(pl.Utf8) + '%')

plot = (ggplot(df, aes(x = "group", y = "rate", label = "rate_label")) +
geom_col() +
geom_label() +
scale_y_continuous(labels = ml.percent)
)

plot.show()


Example in R
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

df = tibble(
  group = c("A", "B"), 
  rate = c(.511, .634)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = rate, label = percent(rate))) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_label() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)



From a look at plotnine's source code, I don't see a way to do it which is simpler than what you've already identified. I don't believe you can supply a callable or Series to the geom_label.

Yes you can do it the "same" as in R.
import polars as pl
from plotnine import * 
import mizani.labels as ml

df = pl.DataFrame({
  "group": ["A", "B"], 
  "rate": [.511, .634]
})

(
    ggplot(df, aes(x="group", y="rate", label="ml.percent(rate)"))
    + geom_col()
    + geom_label()
    + scale_y_continuous(labels=ml.percent)
)


